# Non Blocking calls using Tornado and Python Eve

Tags: python, tornado, eve

I have a Eve Application with Tornado.

```
http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I make a post call on of my API that takes a long time and sends a mail to the user when the process is done.
How can I make the call non blocking so that the user do not have to wait.

Thanks
DC

Answer (score 1):

Eve is written in Flask so by design it's blocking code and there's no simple way to make it magically non-blocking. Running your eve project in tornado will not help either. You can however use [`gunicorn`](http://gunicorn.org/) or [`hendrix`](https://hendrix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can fork your `wsgi` app, act like a proxy, and make it seem like your project is running in a non-blocking manner. But I recommend using an async/threaded task runner (something like [`celery`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html)) to send the mail. This method will require you to rewrite your mailing functions using the task runner. I hope this helps, if not please provide some more examples of what your code does and maybe we can help.

Comment: Thank You. Yes I went through that route. Works perfect. Took me some time to figure.